# Process manipulation

Tags: linux, process

```
$ps -fu $USER
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
kanoujip 22471 21858  0 Sep16 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./Alert_notification.sh
kanoujip 27450 27390  0 Sep16 ?        00:00:00 sshd: kanoujip@pts/9
```

I want to run another time `./Alert_notification.sh` again so want to kill all previous runs from my User ID

How can I achieve this ?

```
ps -fu $USER | grep Alert_notification.sh |grep -vE 'grep|"$PPID"' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill `ps -o pid= -N T` ;
```

terminates all the MY USER session

Comment: Just change your second grep to `grep -v grep`.

Comment: I tried that . I think i didn't explained well. Suppose 1st Alert_notification.sh script is running in one terminal (or in back ground) now i want to invoke another Alert_notification.sh script which should close all previous instance of  Alert_notification.sh running from my User ID on any terminal. killing Process is part of Alert_notification.sh script.

Comment: Ok, can you change the expression to just `grep|$PPID`? The the`'` suppresses parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your request, you don't have to grep on the `$PPID` variable, that is used, maybe, even by your last called script execution, but on the PID of the last called script: `$$`.

If you call `script.sh` using the same `bash`, `$PPID` willi be the same for all the others execution of the script `script.sh` (or `Alert_notifications.sh` in your case).

Try changing something into your command and adding a little of control (if you want):

```
ps -fu $USER | grep  "Alert_notification.sh" | grep -v "grep\|$$" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill 2> /dev/null
```

- `2> /dev/null`: you need it to omit error messages in the case some it will be found no process